# Setting a custom type property in XAML using a static method's return type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm new to WPF and am trying to setup some validation for a textbox. I'm trying to determine if there's a way to set a custom type to a property through XAML by using a static method's return.

In my xaml, I currently have

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider
        ObjectType="{x:Type validators:StringValidator}" 
        MethodName="BasicValidator"
        x:Key="basicValidator"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

...

<TextBox x:Name="StrTextBox" Width="200" Height="50" >
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="TestText" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <local:StrValidationRule ValidatorType="{StaticResource basicValidator}"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Which throws the error on ValidatorType="{StaticResource basicValidator}"

> An object of the type "System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "Validator.StringValidator".

The ValidationRule is setup with a StringValidator property

```
public class StrValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public StringValidator ValidatorType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have a class that builds specific string validators which can be accessed through static methods. For example, the static method I'm trying to call is StringValidator.BasicValidator():

```
public class StringValidator : IValidator<string>
{
    ...
    public static StringValidator BasicValidator()
    {
        whiteList = "abcde...";
        return new StringValidator(whiteList);
    }

    public static StringValidator BinaryValidator()
    {
        whiteList = "01";
        return new StringValidator(whiteList);
    }

    public static StringValidator NumericValidator()
    {
        whiteList = "-012345...";
        return new StringValidator(whiteList);
    }
}
```

And for the ValidationRule,

```
public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
{
    string strValue = Convert.ToString(value);
    return ValidatorType.Validate(strValue).Match (
        Right: result => new ValidationResult(true, null),
        Left: error => new ValidationResult(false, error));
}
```

I have tried using x:Static, but that appears to only handle properties. I'm also unsure if I need to go about this through Binding, but that route pops up many other issues.

Is there a simple fix that I'm simply unaware of, or is there a different approach that I need to follow to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is changing `BasicValidator()` into a property not a "simple fix"?

The underlying problem here is that `ObjectDataProvider` is specifically for use as a *binding source* (as [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.objectdataprovider) explains). Normally, the way you'd use it in a situation like yours is like this:

```xml
<local:StrValidationRule ValidatorType="{Binding Source={StaticResource basicValidator}}"/>
```

But targets of bindings must be dependency properties, and `ValidatorType` isn't one, nor can it be (you have to inherit `ValidationRule`). So `ObjectDataProvider` simply isn't usable in this exact situation.

Given the code you posted, it's not clear why you need the static method at all. You could just create a new instance in XAML, e.g.:

```xml
<local:StrValidationRule>
  <local:StrValidationRule.ValidatorType>
    <validators:StringValidator/>
  </local:StrValidationRule.ValidatorType>
</local:StrValidationRule>
```

Or just make the `BasicValidator()` method a static property instead.

Unfortunately, there's not enough detail in your question to provide more specific advice than that.

Comment: Hey Peter, apologies for the poor explanation.

I use the static methods of the StringValidator class to return specifically built versions of the StringValidator, which I want to be able to drop into the ValidatorType property of the ValidationRule.

For example, I have one that accepts only basic characters like "abc" called "BasicValidator()", and one that validates against only numeric characters, called "NumericValidator()".

I've edited the post a bit, and hopefully that helps explain what I'm after better.

Comment: _"I have one that accepts only basic characters like "abc" called "BasicValidator()", and one that validates against only numeric characters"_ -- okay, but why not just make each of those different static properties? Stuff like this usually benefits from a singleton approach anyway, so that seems to me like it'd be a natural fit.

Comment: Thank you, I was complicating it way more than it needed to be. I initially didn't want to change the static methods to properties as it wasn't written by me initially, but that solved the issue wonderfully.